# Load rails fixtures before classes are loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, fixtures, rake-test

I have classes in my Rails project that are 'registered' with attributes read from the database. However, when I run 'rake test', the classes are loaded before the fixtures are created in SQLLite. As a result, the classes are 'registered' with null values, causing my tests to fail.

Manually testing by running my rails server works perfectly fine, so I don't think there is a problem with my code logic. Also, my fixtures are correct.

How can I change the order of loading the fixtures before the classes and models are instantiated.

Comment: I am having this issue when I am trying to upgrade a legacy project from Rails 2.3 to Rails 3.0. Tests work fine if ran independently without Rake, but if tests are run with `rake test TEST=[test_path]` which runs the test three times (with units, functionals and integrations setups) the tests fail on the first run but pass on the latter two. I am using `fixtures :all` in `test_helper` and the test file itself.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

`rake test` loads fixtures if you specify `fixtures :all`. Run `rake test --trace` to see what happens behind the scenes. I dont think the fixtures are loaded without mentioning `fixtures :all`
 Try to `rake db:fixtures:load` and see if it raises any error.

Comment: That does not help since both test_helper and the test class is loaded only after the models and classes are loaded.

Comment: `rake test` loads fixtures if you specify `fixtures :all`

Comment: Sorry, but you are missing the point. Fixtures load fine, thats not the problem. The problem is the fixtures load after the classes are loaded. I need the fixtures to load before the classes load.